# Best way to implement images alongside object items on CP

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, custom-object, attachment

I have created a News (Custom Object) section in my Customer Portal and created a VF and Apex controller which they are accessed via. Right now I have a simple table of rows with text, however I would like to add images to each news item.

What I would like to know is how can I incorporate this within my code or whether there is a simpler solution?
My solution would be to simply upload an image as an attachment under a certain name (i.e. cover.jpg) which would then somehow be called in the SOQL inside my controller. (the reason I suggest it searches for a certain filename is because each item could contain other attachments used within the detail page)

**VF**:

```
<apex:page controller="NewsController">    
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock id="pgBlock">
        <apex:facet name="header">
            <span style="font-family: Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif; font-size: 1.5em; color:#482371;">News</span>
        </apex:facet>

    <apex:dataTable value="{!newsitems}" var="article" id="theTable" rowClasses="odd,even" 
styleClass="tableClass" columnClasses="col-date, col-title, col-link">
           <apex:column>
                 <apex:facet name="header">Publish Date</apex:facet>
                 <apex:outputText value="{0,date,dd'/'MM'/'yyyy}">
                      <apex:param value="{!article.publish_date__c}" /> 
                 </apex:outputText>
           </apex:column>
           <apex:column>
                 <apex:facet name="header">Article</apex:facet>
                 <apex:outputText value="{!article.title__c}"/>
           </apex:column>
           <apex:column>
                 <apex:facet name="header"></apex:facet>
                 <apex:outputLink value="/{!article.id}">View Article ></apex:outputLink>
           </apex:column>
     </apex:dataTable>

            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Newer" action="{!Previous}" rerender="pgTable,pgBlock"
                                    status="status" disabled="{!DisablePrevious}" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Older" action="{!Next}" reRender="pgTable,pgBlock"
                                    status="status" disabled="{!DisableNext}" />
                <apex:actionStatus id="status" startText="loading..."/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>    

    </apex:pageBlock>   
    </apex:form>             
</apex:page>
```

**Apex**:

```
public with sharing class NewsController{

    public NewsController (){
        CountTotalRecords= [SELECT COUNT() FROM News__c];
    }

    public Integer CountTotalRecords{get;set;}
    public String QueryString {get;set;}
    public Integer OffsetSize = 0;
    private Integer QueryLimit = 20;
    public list<News__c> lstItem;

    public list<News__c> getNewsItems(){
        lstItem = new list<News__c>();
        lstItem = [SELECT Id, Name, Title__C, Publish_Date__c FROM News__c ORDER BY Publish_Date__c DESC, Name DESC LIMIT :QueryLimit OFFSET :OffsetSize];
        return lstItem;
    }

    public Boolean getDisablePrevious(){
        if(OffsetSize>0){
            return false;
        }
        else return true;
    }

    public Boolean getDisableNext() {
        if (OffsetSize + QueryLimit < countTotalRecords){
            return false;
        }
        else return true;
    }

    public PageReference Next() {
        OffsetSize += QueryLimit;
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference Previous() {
        OffsetSize -= QueryLimit;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How I accomplished this some time ago was to take the following steps:

1. Create a text field to store an 18 character ID (the attachment's ID).
2. Create a page to upload the image or choose from one of multiple images attached to the record.
3. Create a formula field that renders the image if one is present: `IF(NOT(ISBLANK(NewsFeedImage__c)), IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?id="&NewsFeedImage__c, "Logo"), '')`

Some adjustment to the formula may be required, as it has been a while since I've built this.